# Laravel SparkForm file upload error

Tags: php, forms, laravel, vue.js, laravel-spark

I'm working on a Laravel Spark project and I am trying to get a form to upload a folder to my S3 bucket. I have the form built:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <input type="file" name="resume" v-model="form.resume">
   <button @click="updateProfile">Update Profile</button>
 </form>
```

Then I have a vue component set up to handle the form submit:

```
Vue.component('resume-links', {
    template: '#edit-resume-links',
    data() {
    return {
        form: new SparkForm({
          resume: ''
        })
    };
},
methods: {
  updateProfile() {
    console.log(this.form.resume);
    Spark.post('/route/to/controller', this.form).then(response => {
      console.log(response);
    });
  }
}
});
```

Then in my laravel controller:

```
$resume = $request->file('resume');

$resumeFileName = time() . '.' . $resume->getClientOriginalExtension();

$s3 = \Storage::disk('s3');
$filePath = '/resumes/' . $resumeFileName;
$s3->put($filePath, file_get_contents($resume), 'public');
```

When I try to submit the form with a file it throws this error: 
`Call to a member function getClientOriginalExtension() on null`
I have tried `var_dump`ing `$resume` right after setting it to the `file()` and what I see outputted to the console is a bunch of `js` looking code
From everything that I reading it looks like file uploads with Laravel is super easy and I don't know why I am having this issue. Any assistance/advice would be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

First of all, your file input needs to have the `v-el` attribute rather than `v-model`.

In your case it would be `<input type="file" name="form" v-el:resume />`.

Next, in your Vue component, you need to gather the FormData so that it becomes possible to send the file to the server. Files have to be handled slightly differently to plain text fields and such.

Add this to your `methods` object:

```
gatherFormData() {
    const data = new FormData();

    data.append('resume', this.$els.resume.files[0]);

    return data;
}
```

In your `updateProfile` method you now need to send this data off to the server as a POST request.

```
updateProfile(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var self = this;

        this.form.startProcessing();

        $.ajax({
            url: '/route/to/controller',
            data: this.gatherFormData(),
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            type: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'X-XSRF-TOKEN': Cookies.get('XSRF-TOKEN')
            },
            success: function (response) {
                self.form.finishProcessing();

                console.log(response)
            },
            error: function (error) {
                self.form.setErrors(error.responseJSON);
            }
        });
    },
```

Finally, in your controller method, you can now handle the file as normal

(e.g., `$request->file('resume');`)

Handling files with Laravel really is a breeze – you just need to make sure you're actually getting them to the server ;)